# Data conversion validation using SQL of 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

As part of a data conversion, data from table Patron from schema 1 (S1) is moved to table Patron in schema 2(S2).

In this conversion, the Pat# gets changed from S1.Patron to S2.Patron and this conversion details are stored in a cross reference table as well. Details of tables are listed below.

`Table1- Patron (Pat#, name, address)` with Pat# being the primary key

```
Tabnle2- xref ( newpat#, oldpat#)
```

Now post conversion, I would need to check if Pat# has been converted successfully in accordance to the xref mapping. I tried the below SQL and it doesnt throw the desired result...I'm a rookie in SQL and any help wuld be appreciated...

```
select a.pat#,b.pat#,c.oldpat#,c.newpat# from 
s1.Patron a , 
s2.Patron b ,
xref c where a.pat# <> c.newpat# and b.pat# in (select c.oldpat# from s2.xref)
```

EDIT-
Sample data

Pre-Conversion -Table - S1.Patron

Pat#,   name,   address-
(A1,    John,   XYZ)
(A2,    Smith,  ABC)
(A3,    Bill,   EDF)
(A4,  Jim,     OXY)

Post-Conversion -Table - S2.Patron

Pat#,   name,   address-
(B1,    John,   XYZ)
(B2,    Smith,  ABC)
(B3,    Bill,   EDF)
(A4,  Jim,     OXY)

Cross Reference Table

newpat#,oldpat#-
(B1,    A1)
(B2,    A2)
(B3,    A3)
(B4,    A4)

I would need to compare S2.Patron with S1.Patron by cross referencing against XREF table for Pat# to validate the converted data. If any errors, I would need to list them. In this example, pat# A4 in S1.Patron is staying same in S2.Patron. Per cross reference the value in S2.Patron should have been B4.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Like @GordonLinoff said, and please don't use [Old-Style Joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Please visit https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp for more information on Joins.  The Venn diagrams on the first page can be very helpful.